# On the correct procedure after answering a quadruplicate question

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Okay, so I just answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116798/show-that-the-following-is-bounded-and-surjective-folland-exercise-5-36/3116845#3116845), and after answering read the "related" section and noticed that the answer had already been asked several times: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109473/functional-analysis-folland-problem?rq=1), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089176/tf-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fnx-n-is-surjective-from-ell1-to-a-separable?rq=1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298636/folland-real-analysis-chapter-5-3-exercise-36?rq=1), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152341/how-to-show-that-this-function-is-surjective-functional-analysis?rq=1).

Now I am not sure what to do, because I don't know what counts as duplicate of what. Logically, it seems that the more recent posts would be the duplicates, but it might also make sense to declare the question with the most answers as "the original" so that the answers aren't lost.

Also, it seems that my approach is different from the one taken in the other answers, so ideally I'd like to post it on one of the questions, but I'm not sure on which one (or maybe even all of them?).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, if you find multiple duplicates and none are closed, you should pick the best formulation of the question to be "the original" (more accurately, the "duplicate target"). It isn't super relevant which has the most answers, as answers can be merged into the duplicate target by a diamond. Just raise a flag and we'll take care of it.

Here, "best" means the question with the most well-written context. I would err on the side of choosing more "background and motivation" context than "my attempt" context. Other details like tags and title can be edited in more easily. In these mergers, it isn't a bad idea to combine the best traits of all the questions into the duplicate target through edits, or to add some exposition to the question yourself.